# How to create a 'shortest-path link matrix'?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, list-manipulation

I am currently struggling with a problem in *Mathematica*.

I have a randomly generated weighted [Barabasi-Albert graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) and a corresponding demand matrix of the same size. I'm generating the graph with the following code:

```
generateBarabasiAlbertGraph[n_, l_] /; n >= 3 := 
 Module[{g = CycleGraph[3], vc, vl, el},
 Do[
 vc = VertexCount[g];
 vl = VertexList[g];
 el = EdgeList[g];
 ec = EdgeCount[g];
 wl = RandomInteger[{5, 20}, {ec}];
 graph = Graph[el, EdgeWeight -> wl, EdgeWeight -> "EdgeWeight"];
 el = Map[UndirectedEdge[vc + 1, #] &, 
   RandomSample[VertexDegree[g] -> vl, Min[l, vc]]
   ];
 g = Graph[Join[EdgeList[g], el], 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Before]], {n - 3}];
   g; 
];
v = RandomInteger[{5, 10}];
l = RandomInteger[{1, 2}];
generateBarabasiAlbertGraph[v, l];
```

I then calculate the shortest path from each vertex `a` to vertex `b` if vertex `a` has a demand from vertex `b`.

Now I would like to create a *shortest-path link matrix* for all shortest paths in the graph. (A similar graph appears [in this paper](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~frank/PAPERS/PRINCETON/pcm0052.pdf) by Kelly).

This is what I already figured out:

```
TableForm[Array[0 &, {EdgeCount[graph], 1}], TableHeadings -> {EdgeList[graph], {sp}}]
```

[image]

As you can see, I have the shortest-path 3-1-4 and need to replace the 0 at the corresponding row if this edge is used in the shortest path. So in this case I need a `1` in row 3 and 4

Any ideas?

Best, 
Julian

Comment: I just added my full code: The Problem I am referring to is the variable "test" in the "Loop" function

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the paper you linked to and your own comments, I think what you really want is a directed Barabasi–Albert graph whose opposite edges have different weight. (Thus e.g. edge `1 -> 2` should have a different weight than `2 -> 1`).

The code you posted generates an undirected BA graph, so allow me to suggest an alternative generating function based on the built-in command [`BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution.html):

```
RandomDirectedWeightedBAGraph[n_, k_] :=
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph @ Replace[
    Normal @ AdjacencyMatrix @ RandomGraph @ BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[n, k],
    {1 :> RandomInteger[{n, 4n}], 0 -> Infinity},
    {2}
  ];
```

This first generates a random Barabasi–Albert graph, gets its [`AdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html), and replaces the non-zero entries with random weights, and uses that to construct a new graph.

We can now generate a (very simple) graph as follows:

```
graph = RandomDirectedWeightedBAGraph[3, 2];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's not obvious from the graphical representation, but the edges do have different weights, as we can check with [`WeightedAdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html):

```
Normal @ WeightedAdjacencyMatrix @ graph
```

> ```
> {
>   {0,  6, 3}, 
>   {3,  0, 7}, 
>   {7, 10, 0}
> }
> ```

Thus edge `1 -> 2` has weight `6`, and edge `2 -> 1` has weight `3`.

Since I don't know what your definition of 'demand' is, I'll compute the shortest paths for all possible vertex combinations:

```
allVertexPairs = Permutations[VertexList @ graph, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```

```
shortestPaths = FindShortestPath[graph, All, All] @@@ allVertexPairs
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```

Notice that the shortest path from vertex `2` to `3` is not simply `2 -> 3`, but `2 -> 1 -> 3`. This is because [`FindShortestPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestPath.html) takes the edge weight into account. The former path has distance 7, the latter 3 + 3.

We can now proceed to compute the 'shortest path link matrix':

```
shortestPathLinkMatrix = Outer[
  Boole @ MemberQ[#2, #1] &,
  EdgeList[graph],
  DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ shortestPaths,
  1
]
```

> ```
> {
>   {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
>   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
> }
> ```

This can finally be plugged into [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) to give the desired result:

```
 TableForm[shortestPathLinkMatrix, TableHeadings -> {EdgeList @ graph, shortestPaths}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Dear Teake, this is really great and works quite nicely on my project. However, there is one mistake. If the shortestpath is calculated based on a weighted undirected graph, I only see the 1 at the edge Position of the first edge and not for rest. I changed the code above with the new one. Any ideas?

Comment: @Julian Sorry, I don't know what you mean here. It would help if you give a small *explicit* weighted undirected graph in your question, along with the set of shortest paths and wanted output. The generating code you have at the moment is not so useful.

Comment: @ Teake, I added the weighted undirected graph too my question. The wanted output still remains the same, your solution was already perfect. It just does not work with my graph object.

Comment: @Julian I added a missing call to `Sort` in the code for `shortestpathlinkmatrix`; try it again and see if it works now.

Comment: @ Teake: now it works like charm. Tahnk You very much

Comment: @ Taeke: How would your solution change if I would like to get all possible combinations of shortest paths, e.g. {1,2}; {2,1}? Currently this solution only yields the shortest path of {1,2}

Comment: @Julian I've rewritten my answer to accommodate for directed edges (which I guess is what you're after).

Answer (score 2):

Taking an example of a shortest-path vertex list and an edgelist from your code:

```
spvertices = {4, 2, 1, 5};
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
         2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
         5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
         7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 2};
spath = Partition[spvertices, 2, 1];
(* {{4,2},{2,1},{1,5}} *)
xx =  Tr /@ Outer[Boole[Equal[##]] &, Sort /@ List @@@ edges, Sort /@ spath, 1];
(* or xx =Tr /@ Outer[Boole[Complement[##] == {}] &, List @@@ edges, spath, 1]; *)
(* {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0} *)
TableForm[List /@ xx, TableHeadings -> {edges, {{4, 2, 1, 5}}}, TableAlignments ->Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear kguler, thanks for your help, but I guess I need a more dynamic version in which I don't have to specifiy all the edges. So far Teake's solution workd fine for me, except that I need to figure out the new problem described above.